# dplyr::filter error must be a logical vector, not a character

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter a `dataframe` based on multiple `ID` values from a column `ID` which has a `character` datatype. When I run the code with `|` (AND) `boolean` I get an error.

How can I fix this in `R` using `dplyr`

Sample data

```
ID      Date     Var1 Var2  
279557  1/1/2020 1    2
280485  1/2/2020 3    4
279556  1/3/2020 5    6
280484  1/4/2020 7    8
267254  1/5/2020 9    10
290512  1/6/2020 11   12
```

Code

```
library(dplyr)

df = df%>% 
  filter(df, ID== '279557' | ID == '280485' | ID == '279556' | ID == '280484')
```

Error:

```
x Input `..1$ID` must be a logical vector, not a character.
```

I know I can create a `dataframe` of the target `IDs` and do something like shown below.

Is this the only way doing this with `dplyr::filter` and `boolean` conditions?

```
target = c("29557", "280485", "279556", "280484")
df = df%>% 
      filter(df$ID %in% target)
```

Comment: Just use `%in%`? Your issue is using `df` again inside `filter` after the pipe. The pipe means you pipe the data into it and whatever function follows can use it. No need to retell them what the data is.

Comment: @NelsonGon, yep that solved the problem, what I silly careless mistake I just made, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, ``filter(df$ID %in% target)`` is unecessary, just do ``filter(ID %in% target)`` instead./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do not need to reference the dataframe in the call to `filter`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10
)

df = df %>% 
  filter(ID== '1' | ID == '5' | ID == '9')
df
  ID
1  1
2  5
3  9
```